# Crash while navigating back after showing List conditionally

Tags: ios, crash, swiftui

Before filing a bug report I want to confirm that I am not missing something obvious.

The app crashes while navigating back from another view after showing a `List` (or `Form`) conditionally. Strangely enough, the app does not crash when there is a view above the list.
No useful stack trace available. The app just crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)`.

***Copy and paste to reproduce:***

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                Text("Second view")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @State private var showList = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if showList {
//              Text("No crash if there is a view above the list")
                
                List {
                    Text("Now navigate back")
                }
            } else {
                Button("Show list") {
                    self.showList = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I noticed this behavior while trying to show a message conditionally when a list is empty. The code above is an abstraction but uses pretty much the same logical structure.

> macOS 10.15.5
>
> Xcode 11.5
>
> Simulator (iPhone 11 Pro)

Comment: It doesn't crash on me. I am running `macOS: 10.15.4`, `xCode: 11.4.1` and `simulator: iPhone 11 Pro MAX running iOS 13.4.1` However it does crash on `iPhone 11 Pro` I think it's Apple's bug

Comment: doesn't crash for me. Mac 10.15.5, xcode 11.6 beta, ios 13.5 iphone 10 and iPad, mac catalyst.

Comment: @workingdog it crashes on `iPhone 11 Pro` can you please run on `iPhone 11 Pro` and confirm? I was going to file a bug report to Apple as well. EDIT: I think it only crashes on a simulator.

Comment: confirm it crashes on iPhone 11 Pro simulator, but not if I add  .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) to the NavigationView().

Comment: It also crashes on my physical iPhone 7. It seems to be screen size related. I can confirm that it does not crash when running in the simulator on iPhone 11 Pro Max or iPhone 8 Plus. And it does not crash at all when using `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())`. I also filed a bug report FB7732783.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding the following to the NavigationView():

```
 .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

Let me know if this works on your system.